# Redirect to landing page if page is 500 internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have an issue while google indexed my old URL where it doesn't longer exist, when someone clicked on the old link from Google search, there will shown **500 server error** in product page.

My old URL for product page is `mydomain.com/item/item-name`, which recently I was re-built a new rewrite rules in .htaccess to `mydomain.com/product/item-name` for SEO wise, I want my old URL at least can redirect to my landing page instead of display an error for the visitor that could build bad impression for my site.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why not you guys don't just tell whether it is possibly to solve instead of just vote to closed the post without any feedback? Disappointed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your htaccess write this :

```
RewriteRule ^item/(.*) mydomain.com/product/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Here all links coming to mydomain.com/item/item-name will be redirected to mydomain.com/product/item-name.

Answer (score 1):

This link provides instructions on how to request Google to remove cached content or wait for Googlebot to reindex, the second part after rewriting .htaccess rules.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/url-removals-explained-part-ii-removing.html

Comment: @AdrianTeh What happens to your answer if the link expires ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Exactly.

Comment: @AdrianTeh No, i am trying to say that your answer will be expired if the http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/ blog was removed or renamed. So, try to add some content to your answer rather than simply giving the link.

Comment: Sure @SulthanAllaudeen, I will take note and thanks for the advice. But you accepted this answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18780022/4749156

Comment: @AdrianTeh That's good to hear. The purpose is to make answers stand valid event the link they provided expired. Thanks for close look.

Comment: I upvoted this, but the advice above is generally sound - we tend to discourage link-only answers on Stack Overflow. There is _some_ preamble here, but since it's a brief contribution, a comment may have worked well also. We prefer answers to be more substantive, I think.

Answer (score 0):

In the short term you can use an `ErrorDocument` in Apache to catch the 500. This can point to a PHP script that can redirect to wherever you choose.

However, you should really find out why old URLs are producing a server error in the first place. If content is being removed, they should return a "not found" page together with a 404 response code.